# Why can't I decode a JSON message in the following situation?

Tags: python, json, flask

I am trying to send a JSON message from a computer to another one via a post request. 
The script which sends the message is the following:

```
message = {'station':'turn on'}
res = rest.send( 'POST', server_addr + "/newstation", json.dumps(message), {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} )
```

The rest.send(...) method should be correct as I used it before and it worked fine.

The PC which sends the post request runs Linux, while the receiving one runs Win 8, if that means anything.

On the receiving machine I have the following:

```
@app.route('/newstation', methods = ['POST'])
def new_station ():
    j_data = request.get_json()
    d = decode_data(j_data)
```

where decode_data(j_data) is the following

```
def decode_data(j_data):
    d = json.loads(j_data)
    return d
```

My problem is: whenever I try to send the post request from the first machine the response is "Internal server error" and on the machine with the server the error returned is "TypeError: expected string or buffer".
Now I am thinking that it may be a matter of encoding of the string.

The post request is received and I can print the json content without problems, the issue arises when I try to decode.

Comment: First, it doesn't look like you need your `decode_data` function. All it does is mask that you're doing `json.loads` there so you may as well do it directly under `new_station`. Second, doesn't `request.get_json` do the parsing for you? I can't tell from the docs and I'm not where I can test right now, but if that's right the `json.loads` call is superfluous.

Comment: The problem was actually the request.get_json method, I misunderstood the documentation. In the end j_data was a dict and I was trying to decode, no surprise it didn't work. Thanks, I finally fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, it was a mistake on my part (of course). I misunderstood the documentation.

```
@app.route('/newstation', methods = ['POST'])
def new_station ():
   j_data = request.get_json()
   #d = decode_data(j_data)
```

request.get_json() already returns me a dictionary, so the decode_data function isn't actually needed. I already have the result without the need for json.loads().

Comment: Glad you fixed it and good job self-answering. I think you have to wait 2(?) days but be sure to come back and accept your own answer later!

Comment: Yep, I'll accept it when I can. Thank you again for the solution.